# why i get this error The widget on which setState _InheritedProviderScope i need to used showdailog inside consumer

Tags: flutter, dart

═══════ Exception caught by foundation library ═══════

The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for AuthService:
`setState()` or `markNeedsBuild()` called during build.

Error i get:

```
This _InheritedProviderScope<AuthService> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _InheritedProviderScope<AuthService>
  value: Instance of 'AuthService'
  listening to value
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: CheckAuthentication
  dirty
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4292:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4307:6)
#2      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.markNeedsNotifyDependents (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:496:5)
#3      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:226:25)
#4      AuthService.getUser (package:mukti/authentication/authService.dart:18:7
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is changing during your widget is building.
Try to use WidgetsBinding inside of initState.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) async {
        // Input method you want change before build.
      },
    );
```

Comment: i tryed this code but is not work

Comment: Sorry for that. Below one is that might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852896/widget-cannot-be-marked-as-needing-to-build-because-the-framework-is-already-in